# Как вернуть результат функции внутри функции

Tags: javascript, функции, циклы

Есть код, который удаляет пробелы вначале и в конце строки:

```
var str = prompt("Введите любое значение");
function trim(x) {
    let l = 0,
    r = str.length - 1;
    if (str[l] !== " " && str[r] !== " ") {
        console.log("no spaces");
        return str;
    } else {
        for (let i = l; i <= r; i++) {
            if (str[i] === " ") l++;
            else break;
        }
        function abc() {
            if (str[l - 1] === " ") {
                console.log(
                    "string has only spaces or spaces has deleted"
                );
                return "hello";
            }
        }
        abc(str);
        for (let q = r; q >= 0; q--) {
            if (str[r] === " ") r--;
        }
        return str.slice(l, r + 1);
    }
}
var ost = trim(str);
alert(`${"<"}` + ost + `${">"}`);
```

я хочу сделать так, чтобы при вводе пустой строки второй цикл пропускался и сразу выводился результат (`return str.slice(l, r + 1);`)

для этого я написал функцию:

```
function abc() {
    if (str[l - 1] === " ") {
        console.log(
            "string has only spaces or spaces has deleted"
        );
        return "hello";
    }
}
abc(str);
```

написал hello в качестве проверки. Но результата нет. Как можно это решить? (p.s. я новичок в Js)

Comment: Использовать в функции переменные, которые не были в неё в явном виде переданы - ужасная практика, обязательно ведущая к ошибкам рано или поздно.

Comment: В каких случаях это выражение будет не верным `str[l - 1] === " "` в функции abc(). И что значит вызов `abc(str)` если принятый аргумент нигде не используется?

Comment: Можно еще воспользоваться регулярным выражением, но врятли это хороший вариант.

Answer (score 2):

```
[...]
const hello = abc(str);
if (hello) {
    return hello;
}
```

Несколько советов:

- Не используйте `var`. Он злой и кусается.
- Функции внутри других функций, вещь не то, что редкая, но необычная. В вашем случае, я не вижу не одной причины, по которой она должна быть внутри.
- Используйте функции для того, чтобы разбить уж на логичные части. Блок кода, который вы привели, слишком сложный.
- Названия переменных должны чаще всего о чем-то говорить о самих переменных. `l`, и `r` не очень удачный выбор.
- Что такого плохого в [уже существующей функции trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)?

Следуя этим советам, и базируясь на коде, который вы привели в комментариях ниже, получаем следующее:

```
function ltrim(text) {
    const length = text.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if (text[i] !== " ") {
            return text.slice(i);
        }
    }

    return "";
}

function rtrim(text) {
    for (let i = text.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (text[i] !== " ") {
            return text.slice(0, i + 1);
        }
    }

    return "";
}

function trim(text) {
    return rtrim(ltrim(text));
}

["abc", "  abc  ", "abc  def", "  abc  def  ", "   "].forEach(
    x => console.log(`<${x}> -> <${trim(x)}>`));
```

Результат:

```
<abc> -> <abc>
<  abc  > -> <abc>
<abc  def> -> <abc  def>
<  abc  def  > -> <abc  def>
<   > -> <>
```

Минус этого кода: он совсем не оптимальный. Пробегать текст два раза, не самая лучшая вещь. Но оставим оптимизацию для отдельного вопроса.

Comment: всё так просто оказалось, благодарю, Вы мне очень помогли

Comment: @StoneSoul Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Благодарю за ценные советы. я понимаю. что можно было использовать trim. Но я хотел попробовать сделать удаление пробелов в начале и в конце другими способами. 

Функцию внутри функции я использовал потому что решил, что это рабочий способ обойти второй цикл и сразу вернуть результат.

Comment: однако не работает код, после вызова функции, пробелы справа не удаляет

Comment: @StoneSoul: Бывает. Вот что. Код, который вы привели, слишком сложный. Предлагаю начать заново, и посмотреть, что получится. Что если начать с того, что код должен удалять пробелы только вначале? Как вы это напишете?

Comment: var str = prompt("Введите любое значение");
function trim(x) {
  let l = 0,
    r = str.length - 1;

  for (let i = l; i <= r; i++) {
      if (str[i] === " ") l++;
      else break;
    }

return str.slice(l, r+1);

}

var ost = trim(str);

alert(`${"<"}` + ost + `${">"}`);

Comment: В точку. Логика, следовательно, следующая: пробегаем текст, и ищем, где находится первый символ, который не равен пробелу. А что если теперь сделать наоборот, то есть пробегаем тот же текст не с начала, а с конца, и ищем последний символ не являющийся пробелом?

Comment: for (let q = r; q >= 0; q--) {
            if (str[r] === " ") r--;
        }
        return str.slice(l, r + 1);

Comment: В каком случае переменная `hello` будет преобразовано в `true`, если из функции вернется строка `'hello'` как у автора? А вызов `abc(str)`? В каком месте функция принимает этот аргумент?

Comment: @StoneSoul: Именно. Первый алгоритм можно записать как функцию `ltrim`. Второй, как `rtrim`, сделав так, чтобы он был независим от первого. Функция `trim` может просто вызывать обе эти функции, чтобы получить желаемый результат. Я изменил мой ответ, добавив пример такого кода.

Comment: @Leonid: Это JavaScript. `'hello' ? 'y' : 'n'` → `'y'`. Про отсутствие параметра, вы правы. CrazyElf об этом писал в комментарии к вопросу.

Comment: А если без ltrim и rtrim?

Comment: @StoneSoul: С какой целью?

Comment: хочу понять, как можно это сделать без trim

Comment: @StoneSoul: Не понял вашего комментария. Я просто написал ваш код в виде трёх функций. Если правильно понимаю, вы хотите соединить код из трёх функций в одну. Я бы не стал этого делать: наоборот, предложил бы разбить код на пять. Поэтому я и спросил вас о цели.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko смотрите, я хочу написать код, который удаляет пробелы как в начале, так и в конце, но при этом, не хочу использовать trim. Плюс хочу его оптимизировать, чтобы он проверял, состоит ли строка из одних только пробелов или , когда пробелов нет в начале и конце

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko Всё, разобрался, как можно сделать, спасибо большое за помощь)

Comment: @StoneSoul: Если читаете по-английски, возможно вам будет интересна [статья](https://blog.pelicandd.com/article/190), где я привожу дополнительные примеры решения проблемы.

Answer (score 2):

В родной `str.trim()` удаляются все пробельные символы, а не только пробел. Регулярка с простой логикой: либо вернуть последовательность из хотя бы одного непробельного символа `\S`, любого количества любых символов `.`, хотя бы одного непробельного символа. Или хотя бы один непробельный символ. Если совпадений не нашлось, то возвращается пустая строка.

```js
function trim(text){
    let match = text.match(/(\S+.*\S+|\S+)/);
    return match ? match[1] : "";
}

let result = ["  lj", "sd lf  ", "lj ", "sl     ", "s ld ld   ", "l", "", "  "].map(str => trim(str));

console.log(result);
```

Это выражение ближе к вашей функции: из строки удаляются все пробельные символы примыкающие к началу строки или примыкающие к концу строки.

```js
function trim(text){
    return text.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '');
}

let result = ["  lj", "sd lf  ", "lj ", "sl     ", "s ld ld   ", "l", "", "  ", "lsd"].map(str => trim(str));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: да можно было бы регулярными выражениями пользоваться, я бы сделал так, но нужно было попробовать другим путём). Спасибо большое за ответ)

Comment: Регулярные выражения - та же подпрограмма, выраженная в краткой форме. Во-первых, trim должна удалять все пробельные символы, а не только пробелы. А во-вторых, здесь описана другая логика, которую можно выразить и в функции.